# update $scope from service property in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and i'd like to know why, in the next piece of code, the "randomN" property of the service is not updating at the $scope.
Since i'm taking a reference to the object's service at the controller with

```
$scope.srvRandom = srvRandom;
```

Why changes at `srvRandom.randomN` are not taking effect?

I think the problem is that "randomN" takes the value of "r" and not a reference to it, but i don't know how to make it work.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("cont", ['$scope','srvRandom', function ($scope, srvRandom) {        

    $scope.srvRandom = srvRandom;  
}]);

app.factory("srvRandom", ["$interval", function ($interval) {

    var randomCreator;
    var r;

    return {
        start: function () {
            console.log("START")
            randomCreator = $interval(function () {
                r= Math.random() * 10;
            }, 2000);
        },
        stop: function () {
            console.log("STOP")
            $interval.cancel(randomCreator);
        },
        randomN: r
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont">        
    RandomNumber: {{srvRandom.randomN}}
    <div>
        <button ng-click="srvRandom.start()">START!</button>
        <button ng-click="srvRandom.stop()">STOP!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you have `return` nothing inside `start` and `stop` function.

Comment: Because when interval is called it assign the randomN variable to window obj not with this factory.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `srvRandom.randomN` which is always `0`.

```
...
randomN: 0
...
```

I think you should do

```
app.factory("srvRandom", ["$interval", function ($interval) {

    var randomCreator,
        randomN = 0;          // Change

    return {
        start: function () {
            console.log("START")
            randomCreator = $interval(function () {
                randomN = Math.random() * 10;
            }, 2000);
        },
        stop: function () {
            console.log("STOP")
            $interval.cancel(randomCreator);
        },
        randomN: randomN          // Change
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your start method to use this for current object not window object.

```
start: function() {
   var that = this; //store this reference to a variable
   randomCreator = $interval(function() {
       that.randomN = Math.random() * 10; // use here
   }, 2000);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

doing this `$scope.Random = srvRandom;` create a local instance of the service obj

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("cont", ['$scope', 'srvRandom',
  function($scope, srvRandom) {
    
    $scope.random = 0;
    
    $scope.$watch('getRandom()',function(newv){
        $scope.random = newv;
    });
    $scope.start = function(){
      srvRandom.start();
    }
    $scope.stop = function(){
      srvRandom.stop();
    }
    $scope.getRandom = function(){
      return srvRandom.getRandom();
    }
  }
]);

app.factory("srvRandom", ["$interval",
  function($interval) {

    var randomCreator;
    var randomN = 0;

    return {
      start: function() {
        console.log("START")
        randomCreator = $interval(function() {
          randomN = Math.random() * 10;
        }, 2000);
      },
      stop: function() {
        console.log("STOP")
        $interval.cancel(randomCreator);
      },
      getRandom: function() {
        return randomN;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont">
  RandomNumber: {{random}}
  <div>
    <button ng-click="start()">START!</button>
    <button ng-click="stop()">STOP!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but i would like to know if is it possible to use directly the variable randomN and not a function. Just to know if is possible or if services must always return objects with function properties.

Comment: you cant use directly randomN as a property of the returned object because it will not be updated by the other fuctions